# php cURL data and arrays

Tags: php, mysql, database, curl

```
...
$query = ("SELECT id, name FROM people");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.externalsite.com/?=".$row['name']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$array = array();
$array = explode(',', $data);
...
```

Then I echo out the value I need

```
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $array[1];
echo "</td></tr>";
```

And it produces a nice table on my web page with many values

```
id|  name  |sales| priority
---------------------------
1 | Johnny | 659 | High
2 | Angela | 13  | Low
```

My question is I currently have the id and name coming from a database and the values coming from external site using cURL. I can order the table with id and name but not with the cURL values, sales for example. What are my options if I wanted to sort the table with sales for example, which I currently can't do?

Comment: the mysql stuff is utterly irrelevant. you could just hardcode that query parameter and the end result would be the same - you need to sort the curl responses before building your html.

Comment: Can't really answer without knowing two things: first, what does the data that comes back look like? What does `var_dump($array);` look like? And second, what does the database query return for values? (Or, at least, what is the data structure of the table `people`?

Comment: Presumably you could use PHP to sort the array before you display it?

Comment: @DxDogo, is your echo statement print html table with values directly? or you are using curl output to print values by adding html table yourself ? If your are adding the html table yourself then better way is use ["datatable"](https://www.datatables.net/). Using datatable you can sort listing by any column in the table.

Comment: @PHPExpert thank you. DataTables seems to be exactly what I need. Didn't know this even existed. The only problem I'm having is it displays only 80 users. When I add the extra 10 users DataTables stops from working and won't sort anyting anymore. Any idea what causes this?